# GPE won't update Drive API v2 past 1.12.0-beta

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I recently started using the Drive API in my Android project, but it wasn't long before I ran into this issue:
[Google Drive InputStreamContent requires length to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063164/google-drive-inputstreamcontent-requires-length-to-be-set)

Basically, I'd like to compress files on the fly, which wasn't possible since the API required a preset length. The issue is supposedly fixed in the 1.13.0 release according to this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=591

However, the GPE won't update my Drive API to this version. Is this expected behaviour, and if it is, how can I manually update to 1.13.0 so I can start using Drive?

Thanks,
Quint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, the Drive API can now be updated past 1.13 through the Google Plugin.